# python b64decode incorrect padding

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I'm sending a file over small UDP packets.  (python 3)
On the server I divide the file into small pieces and do

```
packets.append(b64encode(smallPart))
```

on the other side I do exactly the opposite

```
packets.append(b64decode(peice))
```

However, I keep getting (in all but on packet) Incorrect Padding exception

Is there a standard size for b64decode that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure the data you send is the data you receive? You can always add `assert b64decode(b64encode(smallPart)) == smallPart` to make sure the functions work (they do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description of what you are doing sounds OK. Choice of the input piece size affects only the efficiency. Padding bytes are minimised if the length of each input piece (except of course the last) is a multiple of 3.

You need to show us both your server code and your client code. Alternatively: on the server, log the input and the pieces transmitted. On the client, log the pieces received. Compare.

Curiosity: Why don't you just b64encode the whole string, split the encoded result however you like, transmit the pieces, at the client reassemble the pieces using `b''.join(pieces)` and b64decode that?

Further curiosity: I thought the contents of a UDP packet could be any old binary bunch of bytes; why are you doing base64 encoding at all?

Comment: Machin:
Curiosity: i'm writing the result to stdout, and for big files the impact of join would be great
Further Curiosity: encode to hide data, trying to encrypt files over dns protocol

Comment: @msshapira: b64encode != encryption, it doesn't hide anything; in fact base64 data is readily recognised as such. In any case, have you found out what your problem was? Are you planning on accepting an answer?

Answer (score 6):

Base 64 works by encoding every 3 bytes into 4 bytes. When decoding, it takes those 4 bytes and converts them back to 3 bytes. If there were less than 3 bytes remaining in the input, the output is still padded with '=' to make 4 bytes. If the input to b64decode is not a multiple of 4 bytes you will get the exception.

The easiest solution for you will be to make sure your packets are always a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: 3 bytes into 4 chars would require a multiple of 3 not of 4!

Comment: 3 bytes input = 4 bytes output, so he's saying you should end up with a multiple of 4.

Comment: @msshapira, my terminology was sloppy, I'll fix it.

Comment: -1 You should be able to break the input into pieces of ANY size, transmit each piece, decode each piece, and join the list of decoded pieces. Base 64 encoding routines PAD the output if the input size is not a multiple of THREE. So breaking the input into (mostly) multiple-of-3 size pieces is more efficient, but not necessary.

Comment: @John Machin, I've completely rewritten the answer and now it should be completely technically accurate.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Should be, but it's not. (1) characters??? (2) packet content size being a multiple of 4 is a SIDE EFFECT of ensuring that the data is correctly base64-encoded and not mangled in transit.

Comment: @John Machin, I'm very surprised that the Python3 version of b64encode does not return a Unicode text string as the whole point is to convert to text, but of course you are correct: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode My recommendation to make packets a multiple of 4 was stated to be the "easiest solution", not the only solution - I still stand by it.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: the whole point is to make 7-bit-clean no-special-meaning data for transmission over a network, which happens in terms of bytes -- absolutely nothing to do with Unicode text. Making packets a multiple of 4 is a side effect of a correct solution; it is not of itself a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The length of any properly encoded base64 string should be divisible by 4.

Base64 encodes 3 bytes as 4, so if you start out with a length of string that's not a multiple of 3, the algorithm adds one or two `=` characters on the end of the encoded form, one for each byte shy of some multiple of 3 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding).

The way the alignment comes out, the number of `=` characters also equals the number of characters shy of a multiple of 4 in the encoded form.

Answer (score 2):

I had been trying to decode an URL-safe base64 encoded string.  Simply replacing "." with "=" did the trick for me.

```
s = s.replace('.', '=')
# then base64decode
```