# base64 decode image 'Incorrect padding'

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to decode an image I select from a directory. Once the image is selected I need to decode the encoded string.

I keep getting the error 'incorrect padding'.

Below is the code and the encoded string when I print it.

```
encoded = message['image']
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
```

Here is the string: Its a big string so I hosted it here.
https://www.scribd.com/document/402282670/String

The string starts with

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh
```

Comment: The answer to this question, is this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6102526/6110285 I'd say this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102311/python-b64decode-incorrect-padding) Basically base64 encodes 3 bytes into 4, so if the padding (***=*** character) leaves out 1 or 2 bytes from the decoding, the error you mention is raised

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect padding error is caused because sometimes, metadata is also present in the encoded string. If your string looks something like: 'data:image/png;base64,...base 64 stuff....' then you need to remove the first part before decoding it.

Say if you have image base64 encoded string, then try below snippet..

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from base64 import b64decode
im = Image.open(BytesIO(b64decode(encoded .split(',')[1])))
im.save("image.png")
```

Otherwise, you can simply write it as

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as image_file:
    image_file.write(b64decode(encoded.split(',')[1]))
```